# What is the correct way to make js2-next-error available when using js2-mode as major mode?

Tags: major-mode, minor-mode, javascript, js2-mode

I'm using [`js2-mode`](https://github.com/mooz/js2-mode). It provides `js2-next-error`, but apparently only when using `js2-minor-mode` and not when using js2-mode as a major mode. This is clear from the code in `js2-mode.el` (in version 20230408 of the file):

```
(defvar js2-minor-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map (kbd "C-c C-`") #'js2-next-error)
    map)
  "Keymap used when `js2-minor-mode' is active.")
```

I want to use `js2-next-error` to move to the next syntax warning in a file when using js2-mode as the major mode. Obviously, I can add my own key binding for `js2-next-error`, but the fact that there's no *built-in* way to get it in the major mode makes me think I'm doing something wrong.

Here's my `js2-mode` setup for `.js` files:

```
(use-package js2-mode
  :ensure t
  :mode "\\.js\\'"
  :interpreter "node"
  ;; Hook in helpful minor modes.
  :hook ((js2-mode . smartparens-mode)
         (js2-mode . show-smartparens-mode)
         (js2-mode . highlight-symbol-mode))
  :custom
  (js-indent-level 2)
  (js-indent-align-list-continuation t)
  (js2-basic-offset 2)
  (js2-highlight-level 3)
)
```

Should I be using the minor mode instead of the major mode? Or is there a flag or configuration option I've missed? Or am I supposed to do something else altogether?